# How to get multiple entities from a single Get Query for Azure table storage

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-table-storage, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have list of users created/saved in Azure AD using Microsoft Graph SDK. And every users extra details like (user-status, user-lastGroupId, etc.) are saved in the `Azure table storage`.

Now, I want to get all the list of users from the Azure AD using Microsoft Graph SDK including user's extra details like (user-status, user-lastgroupId, etc.) which is saved in the `Azure storage table`.

So, First I'm trying to Get list of user's from Azure AD using Microsoft Graph SDK. Below is the code snippents.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GetGraphClient()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                var groupMembers = await graphClient.Groups[id].Members
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                var userList = groupMembers.OfType<User>().ToList();
```

Now, I've List of users retrieved from Azure AD which is now present in the variable `userList`

After this, I'm iterating each user in `userList` to get the details like (user-status, user-lastGroupId, etc.) from the Azure table Storage. And adding this list to another List `allUsersWithStatus`

```
List<UserResponseWithStatus> allUsersWithStatus = new List<UserResponseWithStatus>();

                Parallel.ForEach(userList, user =>
                {
                    Response<UserStatusTableEntity> result = userStatus_tableClient.GetEntity<UserStatusTableEntity>(user.Id, user.Id);

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        UserStatusTableEntity userStatusTableEntity = result.Value;
                        UserResponseWithStatus userResponseWithStatus = new UserResponseWithStatus(user.Id, user.UserName, userStatusTableEntity.Status);
                        allUsersWithStatus.Add(userResponseWithStatus);
                    }
                });
```

In the above code, if there are 100 of users in the `userList` then for each user I will have to invoke the *Get query* to **Azure table storage** to get the user details from the Azure table storage.

Here this (`userStatus_tableClient.GetEntity<UserStatusTableEntity>(user.Id, user.Id)`) Get query is called multiple times in a for-loop.

- Do we have other ways to optimize this code snippets to get **allUsersWithStatus** using a single call to Azure Table Storage instead of iterating in a loop.

**NOTE**: I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of `foreach` which has optimized the response time. But, I'm looking for some other ways where we can achieve this without looping and calling Azure table storage Get query multiple times.

Can anyone help me to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge all queries into one filter statement and use them with `QueryAsync<T>()`. You can either do it [by combining expression functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.queryasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-queryasync-1(system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-boolean))))-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) but since that is a bit tricky the easier to read & write option would be imo to create the [odata filter as a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.queryasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-queryasync-1(system-string-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)).

```cs
await tableClient.QueryAsync<UserStatusTableEntity>(
  filter: "(PartitionKey eq 'userid1' and RowKey eq 'userid1') or (PartitionKey eq 'userid2' and RowKey eq 'userid2') or ..."
);
```

It's probably a good idea to still do this in reasonable batches. Also, providing both PartitionKey and RowKey 'should' result in better query performance, but do try both with and without.

Comment: I'm thinking, is it efficient to merger all queries into one filter, if my queries is more than 100's of users. It will be quite cumbersome to create a filter containing 100's of 'PartitionKey' and 'RowKey'. And more over will merging all queries optimize the response time.

Comment: I'm calling ```GetEntity()``` for each entity within a ```Parallel.ForEach```. And by using ```Parallel.ForEach``` the performance has increased as compared to use of ```foreach```. I was thinking If we can completely eliminate the use of for-loop.

Comment: With table storage you'll often have the case where you need to figure out the right way with trial end error. But calling the table storage service 2x with 50 users as filters is most likely faster than doing 100 single requests to the service.

Comment: Okay, I'll try with filters once and will verify the impact. Thank You very much for your help!